# How do I correctly add a lot of vectors? (Java)

Tags: java, vector, physics

I am creating a simulation of galaxy collisions in with only 2 dimensions using the Euler method to calculate gravity(Runge-Kutta would be more accurate, but I did't want to use it for this program). I have "Galaxy cores" as the main gravitational mass and "stars" that act as test masses, but they do not exert any gravitational force by themselves. The problem is that when I populate the galaxy with test masses the orbital velocity, which I have checked to make sure it is correct, does not over come gravity. All the equations should be correct, so I think that there is a problem in the way that I am adding the vectors.

This is the physics library...

```
package Physics;

import MathLib.Trig;
import MathLib.Vector2D;
import Objects.GalaxyCore;
import Objects.GravObjects;

public class Physics {
    public static final double G = 6.674 * Math.pow(10, -11);
    private static final double LIGHT_YEAR = 9.46 * Math.pow(10, 15);
    private static final double DT = 3.1536E12; // 100,000 years in seconds
    public static final double SCALE = LIGHT_YEAR * 5000;

    private static <GravOb extends GravObjects> void calcAcceleration(GalaxyCore[] coreArray, GravOb[] obArray) {
        for (GravOb ob : obArray) {
            Vector2D bufferVector;
            for (GalaxyCore core : coreArray) {
                double dist = Trig.calcDist(ob.getX(), ob.getY(), core.getX(), core.getY()) * SCALE;
                double angle = Trig.calcAngle(ob.getX(), ob.getY(), core.getX(), core.getY());
                double acceleration = dist > 0 ? (G * core.getMASS()) / Math.pow(dist, 2) : 0;

                bufferVector = new Vector2D(Math.cos(angle) * acceleration, Math.sin(angle) * acceleration);
                ob.setAccelVector(Trig.addVector(ob.getAccelVector(), bufferVector));
            }
        }
    }

    private static <GravOb extends GravObjects> void calcVelocity(GravOb[] obArray) {
        for (GravOb ob : obArray) {
            Vector2D bufferVector = new Vector2D(ob.getAccelVector().getMagX() * DT, ob.getAccelVector().getMagY() * DT);
            ob.setVelVector(Trig.addVector(ob.getVelVector(), bufferVector));
        }
    }

    public static <GravOb extends GravObjects> void calcPos(GalaxyCore[] coreArray, GravOb[] obArray) {
        for (GravOb ob : obArray) {
            ob.setX(ob.getX() + ob.getVelVector().getMagX() * DT / SCALE);
            ob.setY(ob.getY() + ob.getVelVector().getMagY() * DT / SCALE);
            calcAcceleration(coreArray, obArray);
            calcVelocity(obArray);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Trig class...

```
package MathLib;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Trig {
    public static double calcDist(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        return sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
    }

    public static double calcAngle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        return atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
    }

    public static double calcAngle(double x, double y) {
        return atan2(y, x);
    }

    public static double calcMag(double magX, double magY) {
        return sqrt(pow(magX, 2) + pow(magY, 2));
    }

    public static Vector2D addVector(Vector2D v1, Vector2D v2) {
        return new Vector2D(v1.getMagX() + v2.getMagX(), v1.getMagY() + v2.getMagY());
    }
}
```

and the vector class...

```
package MathLib;

public class Vector2D {
    private double magX;
    private double magY;

    public Vector2D() {
        magX = 0;
        magY = 0;

    }

    public Vector2D(double magX, double magY) {
        this.magX = magX;
        this.magY = magY;
    }

    public double getMagX() {
        return magX;
    }

    public double getMagY() {
        return magY;
    }
}
```

Edit: I updated the code with the suggestions of the commenters.

Edit 2: The program acts differently if there is one test mass vs many and neither works correctly.

Comment: Well, the answer is in the question: *I think that there is a problem in the way that I am adding the vectors*: `v1.getMagX() - v2.getMagX(), v1.getMagY() - v2.getMagY()`. Why do you subtract the xs and ys? Also, your Vector class shouldn't have its last constructor, and shouldn't have setters which modify their state and break all its invariants.

Comment: Try it with simple 2 objects: a star and a planet, then find out what's wrong

Comment: @JBNizet Whoops ! I did not mean to subtract there, but unfortunately the behavior is the same with that fixed. I will update that in the post

Comment: As @JB Nizet said, you should not allow setters to alter the values after they have been initially set. And even if you were to allow that, your setters are incorrect. For example, If you chage magX then the magnitude and angle of the vector will also change. You can either specify magX and magY, or else specify magnitude and angle. There are only two independent variables, not four.

Comment: @FredK Yeah that makes sense. I will take those out. Unfortunately, I never use those in the program, so it's not the source of my problems.

Comment: If code is not relevant, just do not show it here, as it is just noise for you and for people trying to concentrate on your particular problem (and if you do not need it, do not write it in the first place !)